# What are some applications of graph theory to topology?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

If X has an n-fold universal cover K and is connected then the order of its fundamental group is less than or equal to n.

I realized this when noting the fact that any path from a point x in X to itself can be lifted to a path in K from a fixed point x' in the preimage of x to another point in the preimage (under the cover map). This can be done for every path and then we realize that two such liftings are homotopic relative to their endpoints iff their endpoints are equal. Then we have atleast n classes of liftings since the cover is n-fold. Done.

This is an application of fundamental graph theory. This also got me thinking, what are some other fun applications of graph theory to topology. Are there any applications that go the other way?

Comment: I actually don't see what your main example has to do with graph theory.

Comment: That a graph with n vertices and where every edge is connected to one fixed vertex can have have at most n edges.

Comment: Oh okay. One example I really like which is related to your question is a topological proof that every subgroup of a free group is free. Step 1: Show that the fundamental group of any graph is free. (proof: contract a maximal tree.) Step 2: Show that any covering space of a graph is also a graph. Step 3: Realize any given subgroup as a cover of a wedge of circles.